# The Cucumber JVM's (Groovy) "World (Hooks)" object mixin and Intellij navigation

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea, cucumber-jvm

I am developing cucumber scenarios using Cucumber JVM (Groovy) in intellij. Things are much better than doing the same in eclipse I must say.

I'd like to resolve one small problem to make things even better for my team. But since I am new to Intellij, I need help with the following please:

- When I am in a step def file (groovy), Intellij can't seem to see variables and methods defined in the cucumber "World" object. So don't get IDE support (auto-complete, etc) for those which is a bit annoying. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ IDEA expects **an object** inside World closure. So, you could define the folloing block in EACH step definitions file:

```
World {
    new MockedTestWorld()
}
```

*MockedTestWorld.groovy:*

```
class MockedTestWorld implements TestWorld {
    @Lazy
    @Delegate
    @SuppressWarnings("GroovyAssignabilityCheck")
    private TestWorld delegate = {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("" +
            "Test world mock is used ONLY for syntax highlighting in IDE" +
            " and must be overridden by concrete 'InitSteps.groovy' implementation.")
    }()
}
```

To cleanup duplicated world definitions we use last-glue initializers and a bit of copy-paste:

*real/InitSteps.groovy*

```
def world
GroovyBackend.instance.@worldClosures.clear()
GroovyBackend.instance.registerWorld {
    return world ?: (world = new RealTestWorld1()) // Actual initialization is much longer
}
```

*legacy/InitSteps.groovy*

```
def world
GroovyBackend.instance.@worldClosures.clear()
GroovyBackend.instance.registerWorld {
    return world ?: (world = new LegacyTestWorld1())
}
```

Finally, run configurations would be like this (with different glues):

```
// Real setup
glue = { "classpath:test/steps", "classpath:test/real", },

// Legacy setup
glue = { "classpath:test/steps", "classpath:test/legacy", },
```